# How to config istio virtualservice to do tcp traffic between 2 pods?

Tags: istio

I have a server app listen on 8000 port and a client app which make tcp connection to server. I want use istio sidecar to redirect the tcp traffic, then I do:

1. change client connect address from server_ip:8000 to localhost:8000
2. write k8s deployment and service for server:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-server
  labels:
    app: hello-server
    service: hello-server
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    port: 8000
  selector:
    app: hello-server
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-server
  labels:
    app: hello-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-server
        image: server_test
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

3. write k8s deployment for client:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-client
  labels:
    app: hello-client
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-client
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-client
        image: client_test
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

What's the virtualservice yaml should be?

Comment: You mean 2 different deployments or 2 replicas of the same deployment? If it's just about 2 replicas then everything you need to add is virtual service which will match port 8000 and route it to `hello-server`, envoy proxy distribute traffic across each service’s load balancing pool using a round-robin model so with 2 replicas both will get 50% of the traffic. If it's about 2 different deployments then you can add labels and weight, there is an [example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/tcp-traffic-shifting) in istio documentation. Let me know if that answer your question.

Comment: It is 2 deployments because server client are different docker image. The client pod connect to server pod and send something then server pod echo back, all traffic is in k8s cluster, there is no ingress data so the example you give is unsuitable here, the gateway is unnecssary. In the example you given, the virtualservice spec.host is "*" that is define in gateway, if without the gateway I don't know what it should be, the server pod hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let workload(self app) connect to "localhost:port" and hope istio-proxy(envoy sidecar) to redirect it out is incorrect usage, at least current istio version (1.7). The istio [iptables configure shell](https://github.com/istio/cni/blob/master/tools/packaging/common/istio-iptables.sh) prohibit this by:

```
# Do not redirect app calls to back itself via Envoy when using the endpoint address
# e.g. appN => appN by lo
iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_OUTPUT -o lo -m owner ! --gid-owner "${gid}" -j RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

> if without the gateway I don't know what it should be, the server pod hostname?

As mentioned in [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#the-hosts-field)

> The virtual service hostname can be an IP address, a DNS name, or, depending on the platform, a short name (such as a Kubernetes service short name) that resolves, implicitly or explicitly, to a fully qualified domain name (FQDN). You can also use wildcard (”*”) prefixes, letting you create a single set of routing rules for all matching services. Virtual service hosts don’t actually have to be part of the Istio service registry, they are simply virtual destinations. This lets you model traffic for virtual hosts that don’t have routable entries inside the mesh.

So it should be your service full FQDN name or short name.

In your example it would be `hello-server.default.svc.cluster.local` or `hello-server`.

So appropriate virtual service would look as follow.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: tcp-echo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "hello-server.default.svc.cluster.local"
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 8000
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hello-server.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8000
```

OR

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: tcp-echo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "hello-server"
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 8000
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hello-server
        port:
          number: 8000
```

---

There is an [example](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/tcp-echo/tcp-echo-all-v1.yaml) with tcp server listening on port 9000 with version v1 and v2, tested with netcat from injected pod.

Tcp server with v1,v2 version and a service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tcp-echo
  labels:
    app: tcp-echo
    service: tcp-echo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    port: 9000
  selector:
    app: tcp-echo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tcp-echo-v1
  labels:
    app: tcp-echo
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tcp-echo
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tcp-echo
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tcp-echo
        image: docker.io/istio/tcp-echo-server:1.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args: [ "9000", "one" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tcp-echo-v2
  labels:
    app: tcp-echo
    version: v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tcp-echo
      version: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tcp-echo
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tcp-echo
        image: docker.io/istio/tcp-echo-server:1.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args: [ "9000", "two" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
```

Virtual service to send 99% of the traffic to server with v1 version.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: tcp-echo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "tcp-echo.default.svc.cluster.local"
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 9000
    route:
    - destination:
        host: tcp-echo
        port:
          number: 9000
        subset: v1
      weight: 99
    - destination:
        host: tcp-echo
        port:
          number: 9000
        subset: v2
      weight: 1
```

Test from injected ubuntu pod with netcat.

```
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
one world
^C
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
one world
^C
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
one world
^C
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
one world
^C
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
one world
^C
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
one world
^C
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
one world
^C
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
one world
^C
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
two world
^C
root@ubu1:/# sh -c "echo world | nc tcp-echo 9000"
one world
```

---

There is [iptables schematic](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Understanding-IPTables-snapshot#iptables-schematic) between productpage and reviews services.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work, the client pod connect to localhost:8000 failed

Comment: Could you try with `hello-server:8000`?

Comment: This works, however, this kind of url is irrelative to istio, it only requires a k8s service to working. I want try istio sidecar, so I use localhost:8000 to utilize istio traffic management to redirect the tcp packets to destination

Comment: I aslo tried istio sidecar to configure the ingress and egress of a sidecar, but whatever I tried, it just does't work. Does the url "localhost:port" wrong? According to the work manner of sidecar(use iptable to hijack traffic and redirect), it should work.

Comment: What you mean by irrleative? If you've added istio sidecar to your server and client every request goes through sidecar. You just use mesh gateway for internal calls instead of ingress gateway.

Comment: I mean in this usecase, the work will done with or without istio. Further, the coders might not know what the service name is, if the service name is a requirement, it has to make a series of agreed name bewteen coders and maintainers. Of course, the url can be configured in a file. But that is not the point, I want to know does "localhost:port" is a legal usage in this kind usecase, if it illegal, why?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's illegal or no, it's just doesn't make sense to me.  If your server is exposed with a service how could you get there with a `localhost:8000`? The only way which came to my mind is to use ingress gateway here, which would be configured on localhost, and you would open port 8000. So actually client would call `localhost:8000` which would be ingress gateway external  IP, and with appropriate gateway and virtual service that traffic would be sent to your server. Take a look at link in my answer about iptables schematic between 2 services in istio.

Comment: My motivation is simplify the network mesh at L4 for coder, for example, the server might be more than one instance, the client coder need to manage those tcp connections by itself, and those connections was pretty static, normally established when client app start, if let sidecar(envoy filter writen by wasm) to control the traffic, for coder, he don't need to worry about thoes things, the only one thing he needs to know is the server port. So the data flow should like this: [client pod ---> istio-proxy]--->k8s service--->[istio-proxy--->server pod], all traffic happens in k8s cluster.